# How to install GPU drivers for Intel® HD Graphics (8086:22B0)?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, 18.04

I've got Intel Compute Stick ([STK1AW32SC](https://ark.intel.com/products/91065/Intel-Compute-Stick-STK1AW32SC)), however, after installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver, from [ISO](http://linuxminipcs.com/isos)), I've got the following libGL errors:

```
$ ssh intel-stick-host
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-20-generic x86_64)
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers [8086:22b0] (rev 22)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Configuration Registers [8086:2066]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
$ sudo apt install vainfo && vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.1 (libva 2.1.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) CherryView - 2.1.0
$ sudo apt install mesa-utils && glxinfo
name of display: localhost:10.0
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  149 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  25
  Current serial number in output stream:  24
$ uname -a
Linux ICS-STK1AW32SC 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I install GPU drivers for above Intel HD Graphics?

I've checked on the [Intel download page](https://ark.intel.com/products/91065/Intel-Compute-Stick-STK1AW32SC), but the drivers are only available for Windows.

My goal is to have OpenGL support with hardware acceleration/direct rendering (DRI), so apps such as web-browser can work faster. Currently it seems the generic driver is in use (`i965_drv_video.so`).

I'm running Firefox via `ssh` by (which uses XQuartz on macOS):

```
$ ssh -X intel-stick-host firefox
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Comment: Intel video drivers are included in the upstream kernel and Xorg, and so are already included in a standard Ubuntu Install. Are you running under Xorg? Wayland? Or are you running this as a headless display and connecting via SSH?

Comment: @dobey Above commands were run via `ssh` and I'm running Firefox via `ssh -X intel-stick firefox` on macOS (via XQuartz). Do you think when I VNC to it, it'll make the difference?

Comment: You are getting these results because you are running over SSH, and so vainfo is attempting to query the remote X server. Yes, if you run an X session on the hardware on the intel stick, and VNC to it, it will probably show you more what you are looking to see. Forwarding the X session is not going to use hardware acceleration.